# Linaro toolchain build for armv5 builds for Armv7

Tags: gcc, arm, toolchain, linaro

I'm trying to use the linaro toolchain on Windows to cross compile for an ArmV5 target. My command looks like this:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe test.c -march=armv5te -v -mtune=arm926ej-s
```

With this, the code compiles. But if I readelf the output file, I see it still compiled for an ArmV7 and ignored my flags. Is it really ignoring it and always defaulting to ArmV7 or have I missed something? I tried running:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe --targets-help
```

which tells me it is possible, but apparently not. Also, the code fails to run on my target. I'm planning to use crosstool-ng if this doesn't work. Just a final check before I proceed to that...

Comment: What are you seeing in the readelf output ?

Comment: Towards the end, I see:  
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7

Comment: Try using the '-o' and see what `readelf` says.  I think this issue is libc/libgcc are compiled for ARMv7.  You need the 'C' library (and all dependants) compiled for the targeted chip.  You can use crosstool-ng as others suggest or use `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.  The linaro toolchain a Linux OS on the ARM device.  Are you bare metal?  Then, even if the CPUs match, this will never work.